# Directed cyclic graph traversal to find a path of certain length

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-theory, path-finding

I have a directed graph that looks sort of like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHdW2.png). All edges are unidirectional, cycles exist, and some nodes have no children.

I want a traversal algorithm where the goal is to find a path of length n nodes anywhere in the graph. The algorithm should do the following:

- Starting node is randomly chosen, it traverses its children, and visited nodes is kept somewhere to return a path at the end
- Same nodes can be visited again
- If it reaches a node with no children, it traverses the most recent node with unexplored children. If all possible paths from the starting node are traversed, try starting from other nodes. (I think this method ensures all possible paths are explored)
- Traversal stops when number of nodes visited reaches n and path is returned
- If no path of length n is found, it returns "No valid path"

I'm not sure if an algorithm for this already exists. Most search algorithms seem to deal with finding shortest path, MSTs, and can't visit same nodes. Pathfinding algorithms like A* and Dijkstra's seem overcomplicated for my needs. I might need a modified version of one of these, but not sure exactly which one to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a simple recursive algorithm.  Here's some basic pseudocode.

```
find_path(node, n):   
   if n == 1:
       yield [node]
       return
   for each child of node n:
       for each path in find_path(child, n - 1):
           yield [node] + path
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Node's and Edge's every node keeps track track of all the connecting edges. And the Edges cheap track of the length of the length of the edge and the node it connects to.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, identity):
        self.id = identity
        self.edges = set()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"node <id: {self.id}, edges: {self.edges}"
    __repr__=__str__


class Edge(object):
    def __init__(self, _from, to, length=1):
        _from.edges.add(self)
        self.to = to
        self.len = length

    def __str__(self):
        return f"edge <length: {self.len}, to: {self.to}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"edge <length: {self.len}>"
```

than find a path of certain length like this

```
def getPathOfLength(nodes, length):
    for node in nodes:
        path = subGetPathOfLength(node, length)
        if not path is None:
            return path

def subGetPathOfLength(node, length):
    if length==0:
        return []
    
    for edge in node.edges:
        path = subGetPathOfLength(edge.to,
                                  length-edge.len)
        if not path is None:
            return [node] + path
    return None
```

after creating the connectivity graph like this

```
nodes = []
for idx in range(8):
    nodes.append(Node(idx))

edges = []

edges.append(Edge(nodes[0], nodes[3]))
edges.append(Edge(nodes[3], nodes[4]))
edges.append(Edge(nodes[4], nodes[0]))

edges.append(Edge(nodes[7], nodes[0]))
edges.append(Edge(nodes[6], nodes[7]))
edges.append(Edge(nodes[2], nodes[6]))
edges.append(Edge(nodes[2], nodes[3]))


edges.append(Edge(nodes[1], nodes[3]))
edges.append(Edge(nodes[3], nodes[5]))
```